# Python disable logging for command line module

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

What I'm trying to do seems really simple but I can't find a way to do it. I'm trying to use the module Pipreqs in a script, but I have to use `subprocess.call()` because Pipreqs doesn't have a way to use it in a script. Pipreqs uses logging to log info and I don't want that. Pipreqs also doesn't have a quiet mode. I tried to use `logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)` but since I'm calling it through `subprocess.call()` it still prints info. I've also tried importing Pipreqs and setting the logging level to warning and that also doesn't work. Is there any way to disable this output? My code right now is the following:

```py
import subprocess
import logging
import pipreqs
logger = logging.getLogger("pipreqs")
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
subprocess.call(["pipreqs", "--force","/path/to/dir"])
```

Comment: Can't you just redirect stdout and ignore it?

Comment: It still prints the info

Comment: I haven't tried redirecting is to PIPE, but I've tried redirecting is to /dev/null and that didn't work. I could try redirecting it to PIPE but I don't want to buffer to fill up and I'm not even sure if that would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have access to the logger for an external process. The subprocess module does have flags for disabling output though.

```
subprocess.call(
  ["pipreqs", "--force","/path/to/dir"],
  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
  stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before, but using a different way. I guess my way doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, stdout/stderr redirection isn't entirely uniform yet. E.g. `contextlib.redirect_stdout()` doesn't work for subprocesses, and it doesn't work for output generated by the logging module either -- even by the same process.